# Starting applications with Gnome super key makes some previous windows almost transparent

Tags: gnome

Sometimes, when opening new applications using the super/windows key, some of the previous windows became almost transparent. I can see the applications, move windows, and so on, but since they are almost invisible, there is no other option than close these windows.[image: print screen with transparent windows]

In the included screenshot, there is a Terminal and a Visual Studio Code window full screen, but almost invisible.

I'm using NVIDIA Drivers 450.80.02, on Ubuntu 20.04, GNOME Shell.

As far as I can see, this only happens when using the super and write down the new application name. Seems related with GNOME, but I'm not able to reproduce it systematically. But happens every almost every day.

I need your help to isolate the problem.

Comment: I'm using these shell extensions: Dash to Panel and Ubuntu AppIndicators. It can be some style or render issue related with Dash to Panel extension.

Comment: Same on Ubuntu 20.04. Maybe related with https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=238789

Comment: To get back the window without transparency is to hover the application on the taskbar, and them hover over the small window preview. The Window will be restored to its normal opacity.